# Value Cannot be Null; Parameter Name 'Source'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
 @if ( Model.Select(p=>p.Payments.Any(o=>o.Expires>DateTime.Now))!= null)
 { 

 <table class="table">
     <tr>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayName("Student ID")
         </th>

         <th>
             @Html.DisplayName("Full Name")
         </th>

         <th>
             @Html.DisplayName("Expiry Date")
         </th>

         <th>
             @Html.DisplayName("Contact Number")
         </th>
         <th></th>


         @foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.Payments.Any(o => o.Expires > DateTime.Now)))
         {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentID)
```

This is in MVC project this is the home page I want to show the student who have expired on the current day. I have used the `If` statement and i am confused why i'm getting that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the code and if the model is null you will indeed get the null exception.

[image]

The issue here is with the logic flow as you - first making your selection and then checking for nullability.

In the `if` block - check for null first and then select the results:

```
if (Model != null && Model.Select(p => p.Payments.Any(o => o.Expires > DateTime.Now)).Any())
```